# SQL-запрос с несколькими выполняющимися из множества условий

Tags: sql

Дана таблица с 10 числовыми полями, и 8 условий типа Field_1 < 0, Field_4 > Field_2, Field_5 < 115 и т.д.
Как запросить все записи в таблице, удовлетворяющие хотя бы 4 любым условиям из 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE
  (CASE WHEN Field_1 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) + 
  (CASE WHEN Field_4 > Field_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) + 
  (CASE WHEN Firld_5 < 115 THEN 1 ELSE 0) + 
  (CASE WHEN Firld_3 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) + 
  (CASE WHEN Firld_5 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) + 
  (CASE WHEN Firld_6 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) + 
  (CASE WHEN Firld_7 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) + 
  (CASE WHEN Firld_8 < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0)
  >= 4
```